# Probability distribution of bored people

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

> 5 people are arranged in a row, a person is talkative with a probability of $p$ and silent with a probability of $1-p$, each is independent. A person is bored if he's talkative and sits between two silent people. $x$ is the amount of bored people.
>
> Find the probability distribution for $x$.

So $x\in[0,2]$.

$p(x=2)=p^2(1-p)^3$

Now I have trouble with $p(x=1)$, there's only one triplet with a bored person in the middle and then two spots. So it's either `sts--` (times 2) or `-sts-`:

$p(sts--)=p(1-p)^2(p^2+(1-p)2)$ that's the triplet times either two talkative or silent and then two options.

$p(-sts-)=2^2p(1-p)^2$ that's the triplet and two options for both ends.

When I sum it up it isn't right...

It's supposed to be: $p(x=1)=(1-p)^2p+2p(1-p)^2(1-p(1-p))$

Comment: Point of clarification:  If a talkative person is isolated at an end, as in TS*** is he/she bored?

Comment: @lulu as far as I see from the notes, no. He has to be between two silent people to be bored.

Comment: So the pattern TSSTS would only have one bored person.

Comment: It seems obvious that a person talking by themselves at the end would be bored.  Maybe they can stand in a circle?

Comment: Pl. correct parentheses in book answer.

Comment: I'm with dsaxton, by the way.  I'd be even more bored trapped off at the end...

Comment: That's just how the question was given, I see that in the rest of the answers they didn't assume that trapped in the ends means that they're bored. @dsaxton

Comment: @trueblueanil fixed.

Comment: @lulu Let's just say that the attribute is true when there's $sts$  only and $x$ counts how many times it happens.

Comment: @kuhaku.  Sure.  But then, like I said, you seem to have missed the pattern TSSTS (and TTSTS for that matter).  No?

Comment: @lulu it's the same as `sts--` so as I mentioned it's supposed to be multiplied by 2.

Comment: @kuhaku...Well, I'm with you on p(*STS*) but I don't see where you got your value for P(STS**).  Presumably the $p^2$ comes from TT at the end but where do you get terms like (1-p)2?  Was that meant to be a square?  That would correspond to SS...but what happened to ST?

Comment: @lulu I wasn't sure but it's supposed to be $S*$ where $*$ can be either $p$ or $1-p$, so there are 2 options, I think that's the problem I had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the discussion got a little detailed, I'll just write out an enumeration.  Only way to be sure.

The "one bored guy" states:

one T:  STSSS, SSTSS, SSSTS  3 in total, each with probability $p(1-p)^4$

two T:  TSSTS TSTSS STSST SSTST  4 in total each with probability $p^2(1-p)^3$

three T: TSTST, TTSTS, STSTT  3 in total each with probability $p^3(1-p)^2$

Accordingly, I believe the answer to be:  $$p(1-p)^2\left[3(1-p)^2+4p(1-p)+3p^2\right]$$.

I trust this matches the reference?

Comment: I hoped to avoid brute forcing it. Is it really the same as the answer?

Comment: Well, your method works fine (if you correct the calculation of P(STS**), but I don't see where it is any less brute force than the straight enumeration.  If you had a group much bigger than 5 I'd set up a recursion, but with only 5 that would actually add complexity.  Anyway, my belief is that once confusion has set in it is always good to write it all out (usually you don't have an answer to compare to!).  Of course, you could check my formula against the book directly but that looked tedious..I just confirmed it for a few values of p (as it is a low degree polynomial in p that suffices).